# Python tweepy writing to sqlite3 db

Tags: python, tweepy

My script below (taken from various resources online) isn't writing to the database.  I do not get any errors, and if I comment out the database lines then it outputs to the console without issue.

The database exists, it has 2 fields, its writeable by me....  Any ideas please?

Updated code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import tweepy
from textwrap import TextWrapper
import sqlite3

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''


auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth1.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth1)
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', subsequent_indent='    ')



    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (text, date) VALUES (?, ?)' ,(status.text,))
            print self.status_wrapper.fill(status.text)
            print '\n %s  %s  via %s\n' % (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.source)
            conn.commit()   
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e

    def on_error(self, status_code):
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
            return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
            return True # Don't kill the stream


streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth1, StreamListener(), timeout=None)
setTerms = ['news','hello']
streamer.filter(setTerms)
```

Comment: If indeed `cur` is inside your try block, then you probably want to be passing to `cursor.execute('...', (status.text,))` - note the trailing comma to make it a 1-tuple.

Comment: You need to indent the `on_status` block (it's currently not part of the StreamListener class and it is never called in your code).

Comment: Thank you. Revised script at top - now getting error 406.  Any ideas before I call it quits?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your indentation. You are not getting any errors, because you're explicitly silencing them! with

```
except Exception, e:
    # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
    # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
    pass
```

This catches **any** exception that occurs in the `try: except:` block. Reading the Python  Tutorial is a [good start to learn more about exceptions.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (text, date) VALUES (?, NOW())' ,(status.text))
```

Or this:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (text, date) VALUES (?, NOW())' ,(status.text))
```

In the First case `cursor` is undeclared.

Also, as lqc pointed out, you silence all errors. Don't catch any exceptions to see what's going on or change it to something more specific (like `UnicodeError`).

Comment: Thanks for replies - updated code.  No errors, but records fail to appear in db.

Comment: `cur.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (text, date) VALUES (?, ?)' ,(status.text,))`
You put one value but you have two '?'.
Try inserting some constant and see if it works, we'll know if it's a problem with commention or with tweepy.